# Detecting if stopwords are present in a field

Tags: postgresql, stop-words, tsvector

I am using tsvectors to search for similar entries in a list of keyword I have. In this way I am able to consider the following keyword are identical:

- IT security governance
- it security government

The Problem is that, due to the stopwords logic, also the following entries are considered similar:

- IT environment
- Environment

So, I would like to have a way to detect which records contains stopwords, so that I can treat them differently.
I can add a boolean value to the record to know if it contains stopwords or not.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ts_debug` to find the lexemes that are generated by full text search:

```
SELECT array_agg(lexemes[1]) FILTER (WHERE lexemes[1] IS NOT NULL)
FROM ts_debug('english', 'IT security governance')
WHERE alias IN ('asciiword', 'word');

   array_agg    
----------------
 {secur,govern}
(1 row)
```

To find if there is a stop present, you can look if the lexeme is NULL:

```
SELECT token
FROM ts_debug('english', 'IT security governance')
WHERE alias IN ('asciiword', 'word')
  AND lexemes[1] IS NULL;

 token 
-------
 IT
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggetion of @Laurenz-Albe I came up with this more general solution; based on the value returned by this queries I can distinguish entries with stowords from those that don't have any:

```
select count(*) FROM ts_debug('english', 'IT security governance')
where array_length(lexemes,1) = 0

select count(*) FROM ts_debug('english', 'advanced security governance')
where array_length(lexemes,1) = 0
```